# Should I include the minified file if it's being sourced via CDN?

Tags: html, cdn, minify, web-performance

Let's say I download Bootstrap and get the following files:

- **bootstrap.css**
- **bootstrap.min.css**

Since a minified file isn't exactly easy to read for humans, one would want to keep `bootstrap.css` around for being able to go inside the file and check things out.

But if you're sourcing a CDN like in the example below,

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

what's the point of having the minified version *in your project* when you're just going to source the minified version at the CDN?

My understanding is that by sourcing the CDN, you're decreasing the overall download time since your partitioning where the browser fetches source files (since it can only download a few files at a time per source), which is good! So then why keep a copy of the minified version, that you won't even use, in your project/server?

Comment: Load time isn't just download time. Smaller files are often faster to parse.

Comment: @dman2306 That's what I meant to say, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Any little bit of time you can decrease load times is always considered a good thing. Even while using a CDN loading the minified will load quicker then the non minified version. Of course not by a ton but it all adds up. So although using a CDN does help reduce load time using a CDN + minified version helps even more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wasn't so much asking about using a minified file from a CDN. I'm more so talking about having a minified version of the file literally in your project when you end up sourcing the minified version at the CDN, not your actual project

Comment: @8protons Oh if you are using a CDN there isn't really any reason to have the file on your machine/server. Unless you want to be able to reference it quicker or something while developing.